# type 'JSArray<dynamic>' is not a subtype of type 'List<Ad>'

Tags: dart

I tried two method to parse the rawData into dart objects. One using a for loop `ads` and it works but why `_ads` is not working when I use map ?

```
void main() {
  dynamic rawData = [
    {"title": "a", "id": 1}
  ];
  List<Ad> ads = [];
  for (var raw in rawData) {
    Ad ad = Ad.fromJson(raw);
    ads.add(ad);
  }
  print(ads);
  List<Ad> _ads = rawData.map((e) => Ad.fromJson(e)).toList();
  print(_ads);
}

class Ad {
  Ad({
    this.id,
    this.title,
  });

  int id;

  String title;

  factory Ad.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) => _$AdFromJson(json);

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => _$AdToJson(this);
}

Ad _$AdFromJson(Map json) {
  return Ad(
    id: json['id'] as int,
    title: json['title'] as String,
  );
}

Map<String, dynamic> _$AdToJson(Ad instance) {
  final val = <String, dynamic>{};

  void writeNotNull(String key, dynamic value) {
    if (value != null) {
      val[key] = value;
    }
  }

  writeNotNull('id', instance.id);
  writeNotNull('title', instance.title);

  return val;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The result of calling nearly any method on a `dynamic` defined variable are going to be `dynamic` since the Dart compiler are going through a difficult time guessing the type you want. So when you want the result to be saved into a variable with a specific type like `List<Ad> _ads` you really need to tell the compiler at each step what generic type you want and expect.

With that said, you can get you code to work by changing:

```
List<Ad> _ads = rawData.map((e) => Ad.fromJson(e)).toList();
```

Into:

```
List<Ad> _ads = rawData.map<Ad>((e) => Ad.fromJson(e)).toList();
```

And if you also want to make the analyzer happy:

```
List<Ad> _ads = rawData.map<Ad>((Map<String, dynamic> e) => Ad.fromJson(e)).toList() as List<Ad>;
```